# how to get responsive section of two columns in grapes js

Tags: next.js, grapesjs

```
 {
    id: "b2",
    label: "COLUMNS",
    media: `<svg
        aria-hidden="true"
        focusable="false"
        data-prefix="fal"
        data-icon="columns-3"
        class="svg-inline--fa fa-columns-3 fa-3x"
        role="img"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        viewBox="0 0 640 512"
        width="40"
        height="60"
        style="margin-left: 12px;margin-top: 5px;"

      >
        <path
          fill="currentColor"
          d="M0 96C0 60.65 28.65 32 64 32H576C611.3 32 640 60.65 640 96V416C640 451.3 611.3 480 576 480H64C28.65 480 0 451.3 0 416V96zM448 448H576C593.7 448 608 433.7 608 416V96C608 78.33 593.7 64 576 64H448V448zM416 64H224V448H416V64zM192 448V64H64C46.33 64 32 78.33 32 96V416C32 433.7 46.33 448 64 448H192z"
        ></path>
      </svg>
      `,  
      
      //final content for columns
      //i think problem with the dymic id 
      content: {
        type: 'div', // Define the main container type
        components: [
          {
            type: 'div', // First inner div
            components: [],
            style: {
              width: '100%',
              height: '100px',
              margin: '5px'
            }
          },
          {
            type: 'div', // Second inner div
            components: [],
            style: {
              width: '100%',
              height: '100px',
              margin: '5px'
            }
          }
        ],
        style: {
          display: 'flex',
          'flex-direction': 'row',
          'justify-content': 'flex-start',
          'align-items': 'stretch',
          'flex-wrap': 'nowrap',
          'min-height': '40px',
          media: '@media (max-width: 768px)', // Apply media query to the container
          styleMedia: {
            'flex-direction': 'wrap' // Adjust styles for the media query
          }
        },
       
      }    
  },
```

this is the grapes js column block working fine but its not responsive i am trying to make it responsive at mobile view tablet view how we can do that ..?